# Why is my white space being stripped out from my HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just noticed that my rails app is now stripping out all seemingly unnecessary white space from my fields. It never used to do this, and I have (perhaps foolishly) some javascript that is relying on this white space which is now not working.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen Rails doing this. Perhaps your server is trying to minimize html and stripping out unnecessary whitespaces?